# in HAML what does {%= %} mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I see this line in a .html.haml file (RoR project)

```
.upload
  {%=o.name%}
```

What does it mean? it just prints the output of o.name? I mean, it is the same than:

```
.upload
  =o.name
```

Or does a funky parse.

Thanks!

Comment: it looks like a way to invoke erb..

Comment: It literally prints `{%=o.name%}`, maybe for client side templating.

Comment: there is absolutely nothing in the documentation that refers to `{%%}` `{}` is reserved for attributes, and `%` is reserved for an element. I think that's malformed haml?

Comment: Stefan, can you please add that as an Answer so I can accept it, thanks to all for your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt this is a part of HAML's syntax, so it is probably used on the client-site for templating or other purposes (as Stefan mentioned).